# Subscribe to Facebook "comment events"?

Tags: facebook, facebook-apps

Is it possible to "subscribe" to the event of a comment being posted on Facebook?
I want to have my app react on comments on posts made by app, as soon as they're posted. I can imagine the Facebook API has support for callbacks to apps' back-ends based on certain events, but I can't find it.
I can think of a few hack-y alternatives—e.g. polling for new comments on an interval—but they are too inelegant for my tastes.

Comment: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/real-time-updates/

Comment: I think that's it! :D